# datepicker posting wrong date when user enters a invalid date

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces and JQuery. When I am entering a wrong value in calendar input field and click on save button, an error message is coming with an arbitrary date in the date picker.
It should show current date when user enters incorrect date.

Comment: Can you add your code and the error message ? You are more likely to get help!

Comment: <ai:inputCalendar id="txtVat_Valid_Untl_Date" widgetVar="vat_Valid_Untl_Date_var"
     label="#{taxes.vatValidUntlDate_dp}"
     value="#{taxesBean.taxesTO.vatValidUntlDate}" 
          readonly="#{taxesBean.isReadOnly}"
          required="true" requiredMessage="#{taxes.VALID_UNTIL_DATE}"
     maxlength="0"
     showTime="false">  
    </ai:inputCalendar>

Comment: If i am entering 4444444 in the input filed, datepicker is showing 20 March 14184. Please help.